# DHCP IP lease attempt failed over Ethernet and DHCP with netctl

Tags: dhcp, netctl

My DHCP Ethernet works fine in Windows,
but not in Arch Linux with `netctl` and `dhcpcd`. 
What am I doing wrong?

**Output of `ip link`**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp2s0: [...]
3:  eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [my mac adress] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**My `netctl` profile**

```
$ cat /etc/netctl/dhcp
Description='ethernet dhcp'
Interface=eno1
Connection=ethernet
IP=dhcp
#IP6=dhcp
#IP6=stateless
```

**Error message after `sudo netctl start dhcp`**

```
$ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Fr 2013-12-27 13:25:36 CET, end at Mo 2014-01-13 12:45:22 CET. --
Jan 13 12:44:50 laptop2 network[697]: DHCP IP lease attempt failed on interface 'eno1'
Jan 13 12:44:50 laptop2 network[697]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'dhcp'
Jan 13 12:44:50 laptop2 systemd[1]: netctl@dhcp.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 13 12:44:50
laptop2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile dhcp.
```

OK, so it has problems getting the network up, doing it myself...

```
$ sudo ip link set eno1 up
$ sudo netctl start dhcp
Job for netctl@dhcp.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl@dhcp.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
$ sudo journalctl -xn
[...]
Jan 13 12:47:20 laptop2 network[1304]: Starting network profile 'dhcp'...
Jan 13 12:47:20 laptop2 network[1304]: The interface of network profile 'dhcp' is already up
Jan 13 12:47:20 laptop2 systemd[1]: netctl@dhcp.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 13 12:47:20 laptop2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile dhcp.
```

**This doesn't help either, setting it down again.**

```
$ sudo ip link set eno1 down
```

**Trying it with `dhcpcd`...**

```
$ sudo systemctl start dhcpcd
$ ping www.google.de
connect: Network is unreachable
$ ip link
[...]
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
[...]
$ sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd

$ sudo netctl start dhcp
Job for netctl@dhcp.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl@dhcp.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

$ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Fr 2013-12-27 13:25:36 CET, end at Mo 2014-01-13 12:53:06 CET. --
Jan 13 12:52:36 laptop2 dhcpcd[1753]: version 6.1.0 starting
Jan 13 12:52:36 laptop2 dhcpcd[1753]: eno1: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jan 13 12:53:06 laptop2 dhcpcd[1753]: timed out
Jan 13 12:53:06 laptop2 dhcpcd[1753]: exited
Jan 13 12:53:06 laptop2 network[1707]: DHCP IP lease attempt failed on interface 'eno1'
Jan 13 12:53:06 laptop2 network[1707]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'dhcp'
Jan 13 12:53:06 laptop2 systemd[1]: netctl@dhcp.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 13 12:53:06 laptop2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile dhcp.
```

After deleting the lease at `/var/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-eno1.lease6` and trying again, I still get the same error message. 
Writing `TimeoutDHCP=40` to `/etc/netctl/hooks/timeout` and making it executable also changes nothing.

Comment: Why not just try the new networkd?
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP ([Konrad Höffner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22513/konrad-h%c3%b6ffner)) posted this answer
in his question [on Oct 21 ’14 at 7:22](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/109132/2):

> #### Solved
>
> The network cable was defective. 
>   I switched it out and it works again.